# Java's logical OR operator does not evaluate right hand side despite that right hand side has a unary operator?

Tags: java, operator-precedence, unary-operator, logical-or

Given that:

```
Object x = null;
```

Consider code snippet #1:

```
if (x == null || !x.equals(new Object()))
    System.out.println("I print!");
```

Code snippet #1 does not throw a `NullPointerException` as I first thought it should have. I can provoke the exception with a little bit of help from the `|` operator. Code snippet #2:

```
if (x == null | !x.equals(new Object()))
    System.out.println("This will throw a NullPointerException..");
```

How come then that my first code snippet never evaluated the right expression that has a unary NOT operator in it (the exclamation `!`)? According to.. well all web sites out there.. the unary NOT operator has higher precedence that that of the logical OR operator (`||`).

Comment: Because if the first condition in an `OR` is true, what is the point of evaluating the second?

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is that the unary NOT operator (!) has higher precedence, he should be evaluated before the OR operator. Or so I thought!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the unary NOT operator has higher precedence that that of the logical OR operator (||).

Yes it's true. But the precedence thing will come into effect, if you use NOT on the first expression of logical OR.

Consider the condition:

```
if (!x.equals(y) || y.equals(z))
```

In this case, the negation will be applied first on the result of `x.equals(y)`, before  the logical OR. So, had the precedence of `||` been greater than `!`, then the expression would have been evaluated as:

```
if (!(x.equals(y) || y.equals(z)))
```

But it's not. As you know why.

However, if the NOT operator is on the second expression, the precedence is not a point here. The first expression will always be evaluated first before the 2nd expression. And short-circuit behaviour will come into play.

Comment: Thank you for your example. It was that example, together with Peter Lawrey's "precedence = where the implied brackets are" that ultimately got me going in the right direction. Any one else having the same issues as I should consider this code: `if (one() || two() && three())`. The `&&` operator too has higher precedence than the `||` operator has. But the if clause is evaluated as such: `if (one() || (two() && three()))`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common misconception that precedence == order of evaluation.  This is not always the case.  Precedence determines the order the compiler builds the expression and this can lead the code generated to match that order, but in some cases, e.g. post increment and short curcuit operators that this doesn't apply.

All precedence means is to where the implied brackets are e.g.

```
if (x == null || !x.equals(new Object()))
```

is the same as

```
if ((x == null) || (!(x.equals(new Object()))))
```

Comment: +1. "All precedence means is to where the implied brackets are"

Comment: Yeah that precedence thing was really helpful. For me, it was Rohit Jain's example that got me thinking straight so I had to mark his answer as the accepted one. Peter, your note on the "precedence = where the implied brackets are" was truly helpful. See my comment to Rohit for an example I managed to construct with your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [this Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). The `||` and `&&` short circuit execution if the first boolean expression results in `true` or `false`, respectively.

The unary `!` has higher precedence than the bitwise OR `|`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for precedence rules.

Comment: I know about the short circuit, but the unary NOT has higher precedence than the logic OR operator?

Comment: @Martin Yes, it does. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @MartinAndersson Precedence and order-of-evaluation are different issues. Think of precedence as telling you where to put the parentheses to get a full-parenthesized expression equivalent to the original one. Order of evaluation is specified for each operator.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - in the logical OR statement (`||`) the second argument is only evaluated if the first is false.

With the second operator (a [bitwise inclusive or](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html), `|`), both arguments are evaluated (it doesn't short-circuit). Therefore, because `x` is null, the second one will throw a `NullPointerException` while the first won't.

Answer (score 0):

If Java is anything like C# on this front, logical operators like `||` and `&&` are evaluated left-to-right. if `p == true` then `p OR q == true`, by definition, so evaluating the right-hand of the `OR` is pointless.

This is stops you having to do things like this (and, of course, is more efficient than evaluating a load of redundant expressions):

```
if (x != null)
{
    if (x.Property > 0)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure how precedence is relevant here, as the `NOT` excludes the first expression in the provided conditional, so the value of the right hand has no bearing on the value of the left hand anyway.